# Inset Faces tool not working properly and shows a yellow circle

Tags: modeling

I have a problem with the inset faces tool. I've added a cylinder and used the loop cut tool in the edit mode to cut the cylinder from the bottom. I want to horizontally extend or extrude the highlighted spot under the cylinder. I select the bottom part and press the inset faces tool on the left of the menu but I'm getting a yellow circle. When I hover on it it becomes white. I try to drag with the mouse pressed but I only see a dotted gray or black line and nothing happens. I searched on internet. People are using the <kbd>I</kbd> key to apply the inset, but this doesn't work for me. Normally when I select a cutted portion of a mesh I see a yellow line with a yellow circle in it to drag it to apply the effect. For example with the bevel tool, you see this yellow stripe with a yellow circle which you can press the mouse button to drag with. I don't see this also. I worked in the wireframe mode to do this, but can't get it to work.
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work. When the circle turns white, hold the left mouse button down and move it towards the centre of the object. You may have to do that with the shift key held down to slow the movement down. What do you see happening? - It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

> The yellow circle is the tool gizmo. I'm assuming you are dragging from the center of the circle outwards. The gizmo is the area that you are supposed to drag in. **You should be dragging anywhere from near the circle's edge** *(not outside or FROM the inside)* **TOWARDS the circle's center**. The dotted line is part of the inset tool.

You can just press <kbd>I</kbd> which is the inset tool short cut and it works the same, but you won't have the yellow circle on the screen and you don't have to click and start dragging again. It starts insetting while you move your mouse the moment you press <kbd>I</kbd>.

Gif example. (Press <kbd>I</kbd>, then move your mouse)

[image]